# compile Java to native Android instead of writing in C

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

We are looking for a way to protect our code and obfuscation is not enough.
Is it possible to compile Android java code to a native Android library?

Another option would be to write the code in c and connect with it through JNI ourselves. But the code we have is quite elaborate and well tested, a rewrite to c would start the testing all over.

PS: Before we were running on x86 hardware and used Excelsior Jet as a means for protection. As we want to move to more cost-effective (cheaper) Arm/android hardware we are looking for a simular solution as Jet, which alas only compiles to x86.

Comment: We rewrote it in C++. It is not so complicated, as long you write unit tests.

Comment: Ai, you got us there :). We have some unit tests, but not enough. The code has been optimized during pilot projects and production over the last 6 years. Adding unit tests in retrospective can be quite hard as it involves people triggering sensors at unpredictable intervals. Would be a good reason to write more tests though.

Comment: Is it really worth time to consider this? If you need protection, look for protection. This is another level of obfuscation. Depends on what you do and how unique it is. But I think, if you spend same time improving your code AND your business model, it would be better invested. Or make only critical pieces in native, rest in Java. You know, native is harder do debug and analyze. Even native code can be decompiled, it is only harder. If it is worth, it will be done. If not, why would you do it? If you need, consider online model where your code does not leave your hands.

Comment: @Pihhan I share your thoughts, we had the same discussion here: is native really better than just proguard obfuscation? Our aim is to have just a part of our code in native, rest will be Java, just as you suggest. As to whether it is worth it: its an algoritme that can not run in the cloud and has been under development for years and years. Next to that: it is not my call, company owner will not allow a move to Arm until there is good alternative for the native compilation we have now.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should be able to use LLVM. It has:

- A Java frontend
- [A C backend](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2OTg)

In principle, this could do what you need. However I imagine you'd need to distribute (in compiled form) lots of the Java class library. All in all, it sounds really hard. And someone who really wants to read the code won't have too much problem with ARM disassembly...

Comment: That sounds like an interesting option, if one can do that for only part of the code. Depends on how mature both steps are. Any idea how you would call the resulting code from the non converted java?

Comment: I'd only attempt something as insane if the Java code were strictly an algorithm with no significant external dependencies. In which case, just one extra C file with a bit of simple JNI should enable you to call into this... perhaps!